# Can't view debug logs in Developer Console - Failed to load data Log from Salesforce.com: Salesforce automatically deletes system logs 24 hours

Tags: developer-console, logging, debug-logs

The following error is coming up in a Sandbox Developer Console no matter what I try and it's been like this for weeks.

Video: https://www.screencast.com/t/ULztMIi0edS0

*Failed to load data Log from Salesforce.com: Salesforce automatically deletes system logs 24 hours after they’re generated. If the log you had open was less than 24 hours old, someone deleted it. To save logs, select File > Download Log.*

[image]

Note: I can still see debug logs if I go to *Administration Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs* and then add my user, but I would really like to use the Developer Console as I can't refresh this sandbox anytime soon. I've tried deleting ApexLog records manually as well as the clearing out IDEWorkspace data via the blogpost below.

Any thoughts on how to proceed? How can I get debug logs to work like they should in this sandbox?

**Deleting ApexLog records in console:** Select Id from ApexLog

**Clearing out IDE preferences blog:** http://daeheui.com/2021/05/03/salesforcefailed-to-load-data-log-from-salesforce-com-salesforce-automatically-deletes-system-logs-24-hours-after-theyre-generated-if-the-log-you-had-open-was-less-than-24-hours-old-someone-del/

Comment: i see this message all the time and just click OK; then use DC normally

Comment: Thanks... Unforunately we literally can't open debug logs without going into setup and logging 'User Trace Flags' against our user. It won't load in the developer console even after clicking OK.

Comment: log a case with sf -- seen same in last 2 days in 3 orgs

Comment: That error is a generic error. If you check your browser's developer console (F12), do you see any errors on the browser's console? I'll try to replicate in a few orgs, if I can see what's up.